# Magmi Magento Reindexer v1.0.2

Tags: magmi, importexport, reindex, indexer

What should be entered in the box labelled "PHP CLI command" for this option for reindexing products via Magmi? Should it be just left as "php" or should it be "php indexer.php" or something different? I've tried various combinations but nothing seems to actually get our products running through the indexes in Magmi.

I've read the documentation here:

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Magmi_Magento_Reindexer

We use the "On the fly indexer v0.1.5" currently, so are leaving boxes for calalog_url & catalog_category_product unchecked as directed.

Our products get imported fine into our store. But the url's don't get created and the products don't go into our search in frontend. If we update prices of existing items via Magmi, the prices don't update. So I fear the command we have in the "Magmi Magento Reindexer" field is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing, try entering `php-cli` into the **PHP CLI command** field.

If you're running Magmi using a browser, the indexer may fail due to a few possible reasons.

1. Reindexing the **catalog_url** and **catalog_category_product** indexes can take a very long time for a site with a lot of products.  If the amount of time exceeds the timeout limit set on PHP, the script will stop running prematurely and not fully reindex the site.  For this reason the [On the fly indexer](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=On_the_fly_indexer) was created so these indexes would be handled as items are imported/updated.
2. If you're receiving the error `This script cannot be run from Browser. This is the shell script.`, this is because the **/shell/abstract.php** file prevents the indexer.php file from being run from the browser.  A temporary fix would be to open up **/shell/abstract.php**, look for `die('This script cannot be run from Browser. This is the shell script.');` and commenting it out.
3. Last resort, try running your index process using a SSH connection by running the following command: `php indexer.php reindexall`.  Wait to see if everything completes without error. (Note, you must first `cd` into the `/shell` directory before running the indexer command.)

Comment: Hi @Axel many thanks for your feedback. We've tried php-cli but that hasn't changed anything for us unfortunately. Assuming there should be no space between php and -cli ? In honesty, I think our issues might be the size of our catalogue, we have around 150,000 products now. But I thought when running the indexes via Magmi, they would just affect the uploaded products from that csv upload? Not full catalogue of 150,000 products?

Comment: Reindexing applies to all of the products.  I recommend trying the other solutions I posted in my answer.  With your catalog size, try reindexing directly from the shell (SSH connection).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We are able to index via SSH (shell) successfully and always have been. This currently takes an age to run though. For example, catalog url index alone takes around 3 hours! We used to be able to index successfully from Magmi directly, but I guess it is purely the size of the catalog that is stopping the indexes running? Is "php-cli" into the PHP CLI command field definitely correct?